# Degree of a differential equation, a paradox

Tags: calculus

It is understood that the degree of the differential equation 
y"=x^1/5 is 1.
Let it's solution be y(x,c).
Then there is another equation(actually the same) 
(y")^5=x
whose solution is same as that for the previous equation. 
So if a question is asked that what is the degree of the second differential equation, what will be the answer--1 or 5?

Comment: The degree of both differential equations is $2$. Degree is based on the highest order derivative, which is always an integer value.

Comment: You're confusing to definition of degree within polynomials and degree within differential equations.

Comment: I think with differential equations, I've mostly heard "order", not "degree".